# What is the Impostor Level?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Has anyone else gotten a level called the Impostor? It's supposedly a food place but they only sell more Impostor products. Is it an error in the game or a temporary thing until a new level comes out? I had a bitizen with an Impostor dream job but I jettisoned him out the airlock weeks ago :(

Answer (score 4):

The impostor levels always appear as food levels.

What has happened is the developer added new floors to the game, and the servers know about it, however your game client has not updated fully yet to know about the new level.

Usually force closing the game and reopening it will get the game client to complete the update, however in some cases you may need to go to the play store (or app store) to force the game client to update.

After you update everything marked as impostor will change to the real level the server wants you to have; this may change your level from food to something else.

Answer (score 0):

The impostor dream job is actually a glitch in the game.  People who have gotten this have reported that when they exit the game and re-enter the bitizen's dream job changes back to a real place.

I believe it to be a place holder that the developers use for pushing out the bitizens, and it gets replaced by their real dream job.

There is no Impostor level that anyone has reported.

Answer (score 0):

I have both Impostor Bitizens and an Impostor level.  Although my Impostor level does show up as food, it's an Imperial level.  All really weird.  And as far as I know my game is up to date, it did an update about two weeks ago and again a week ago.

In my case, yes, shutting down the game and re-starting it did re-tag the level as "Shuttle Bay" and evicted/deleted the Bitizen.